# Downloader for Launchpad?

Tags: ubuntu, bazaar, launchpad

When downloading a branch on launchpad (it's big) I get a connection reset by peer error. I'm wondering is there a downloader for launchpad? Also if there's is a resume function it would be awesome. I'm using bzr on the command line BTW.

Thanks in advance!

P.S.
I'm using Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Some projects may offer a tarball of the main branch for download.
Otherwise you should try to only get a couple of revisions at a time eg.

```
bzr branch -r100 lp:<project>
cd <project>
bzr pull -r200
```

etc.
It will be nice to fix/automate this one day.
Bazaar will always keep what it successfully downloaded, but sometimes it may try to get too much at a time for some networks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a history-less lightweight checkout:

```
bzr checkout --lightweight lp:<project>
```

More details in the [Bazaar docs](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/beta/en/user-guide/using_checkouts.html).